# Is there anyway to view the embedded resources of an Android app?

Tags: android

I need to view the embedded resources of an Android app?  Is there anyway to do that if I have the binary for the app?
Thanks

Comment: An apk is a zipped file.

Comment: Try online via http://www.decompileandroid.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use APKTool:
http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Install it:
http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

Download tool and in a command line run:

```
apktool d my_app.apk
```

Comment: @user1314333 Is it useful ?